# python shorthand method for a if-else based on the function's return

Tags: python

I have read examples of python shorthand-if in the stackoverflow but still can not figure out how to solve my own simple problem. 
I want to `print("this is a prime number")` else `print(this is not a prime number)` based on the [boolean] return value of the following function:

```
is_prime(2)
```

How should I write a short hand method for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)?

```
print("this is a prime number" if is_prime(2) else "this is not a prime number")
```

---

```
print('this {} a prime number'.format('is' if is_prime(2) else 'is not'))
```